# ValueError when using custom new in Python Enum

Tags: python, enums

I'm encountering an issue with the following Python code where a ValueError is raised when trying to create an instance of an Enum with a value that doesn't correspond to any defined enum member:

```
from enum import Enum

class Option(Enum):
    OPTION_1 = "Option 1"
    OPTION_2 = "Option 2"
    NONE = ""

    def __new__(cls, value):
        try:
            obj = object.__new__(cls)
            obj._value_ = value
            return obj
        except ValueError:
            return Option.NONE

tmp = Option("Option 3")
```

The ValueError seems to be related to how the `__new__` method is handling the invalid values. I want the code to create an instance of the `NONE` member in case an invalid value is provided, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Why is this code resulting in a ValueError and how can I achieve the desired behavior of using the `NONE` member for invalid values?

Comment: What is the traceback of the ValueError?

Comment: Could the problem be that by invoking `object.__new__(cls)` rather than `super().__new__(cls)` that the `__init__` method of Enum isn't getting invoked?  See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__new__` method is used during enum class creation; after that `Enum.__new__` is swapped in, and it only does look-ups.

To handle situations like these, use the [`_missing_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum._missing_) method:

```
@classmethod
def _missing_(cls, value):
    return cls.NONE
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Interesting that this hook works for lookups with `__new__`, but not for `__getitem__` nor `__getattr__`.

Comment: @wim, `__getitem__` and `__getattr__` are both for getting the member directly from it's name, which hopefully one knows; `_missing_` is for getting the member from a value, and there are many reasons why a value might need adjusting, or just returning a default.  My `aenum` library does have a corresponding missing method for names (not sure if anyone uses it).